# Rewrite SQL query for MariaDB using JPA projection

Tags: sql, jpa, mariadb, jpa-2.0, jpql

I want to rewrite native SQL query to JPQL query:

```
SELECT count(id) as count, status, error_class, error_message, id, settlement_status_raw FROM `payment_transactions` WHERE `payment_transactions`.`terminal_id` = 16 AND (created_at > '2019-06-01 00:00:00.000000') AND (`payment_transactions`.`status` != 'approved') GROUP BY `payment_transactions`.`error_message`  ORDER BY count DESC
```

I tried this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO(count(e.id) as count, e.status, e.error_class, e.error_message) " +
            " FROM payment_transactions e " +
            " WHERE e.terminal_id = :id AND (e.created_at > :created_at) " +
            " AND (e.status != 'approved') ", nativeQuery = true)
```

But I get error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '.' near line 1, column 96 [SELECT new PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO(e.id, count(id) as e.count, e.status, e.error_class, e.error_message)  FROM payment_transactions e  WHERE e.terminal_id = :id AND (e.created_at > :created_at)  AND (e.status != 'approved')  GROUP BY e.error_message  ORDER BY e.count DESC]"}}
```

Do you know what is the proper way to implement this query into JPQL for MariaDB?

DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer count;

    private String status;

    private String error_class; 

    private String error_message;
}
```

Comment: Can you post `PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO` class as well

Comment: Post is updated

Comment: mm, I'd suspect the as clause `as e.count` it is useless anyway try removing it also you should use the full classpath e.g `SELECT new com.package.PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO` to avoid any conflicts if same class name exist

Comment: ok, do you see other JPQL syntax mistakes?

Comment: No actually query look ok apart from the `as` clause offcourse